# make the bash script to be faster

Tags: bash

I have a fairly large list of websites in "file.txt" and wanted to check if the words "Hello World!" in the site in the list using looping and curl.

i.e in "file.txt" :

```
blabla.com
blabla2.com
blabla3.com
```

then my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
put() {
printf "list : "
read list
run=$(cat $list)
}
put
scan_list() {
for run in $(cat $list);do
if [[ $(curl -skL ${run}) =~ "Hello World!" ]];then
printf "${run} Hello World! \n"
else
printf "${run} No Hello:( \n"
fi
done
}
scan_list
```

this takes a lot of time, is there a way to make the checking process faster?

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net first, by pasting your code there.

Comment: indeed when I try to check on the shellcheck.net it's an error, but this is just an example, and when I run my script in the terminal it doesn't get an error.

Comment: Use GNU parallel to run multiple curl requests at the same time.

Comment: is there an example of how to combine my code with GNU Parallel?

Comment: `xargs` might be another option for concurrent curl requests.

Comment: can someone give an example?

Comment: There's a _lot_ wrong with this code. Don't use external commands where shell builtins will do. Avoid forking -- that means no subshells, no command substitutions, etc -- inside loops. In general, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Avoid unquoted expansions, and anything else http://shellcheck.net/ warns about.

Answer (score 1):

Use xargs:

```
% tr '\12' '\0' < file.txt | \
    xargs -0 -r -n 1 -t -P 3 sh -c '
    if curl -skL "$1" | grep -q "Hello World!"; then
      echo "$1 Hello World!"
      exit
    fi
    echo "$1 No Hello:("
  ' _
```

- Use **tr** to convert returns in the `file.txt` to nulls (\0).
- Pass through **xargs** with -0 option to parse by nulls.
- The -r option prevents the command from being ran if the input is empty. This is only available on Linux, so for macOS or *BSD you will need to check that file.txt is not empty before running.
- The -n 1 permits only one file per execution.
- The -t option is debugging, it prints the command before it is ran.
- We allow 3 simultaneous commands in parallel with the -P 3 option.
- Using sh -c with a single quoted multi-line command, we substitute $1 for the entries from the file.
- The _ fills in the $0 argument, so our entries are $1.

Comment: If you're using `&&` for flow control, consider adding explicit grouping to avoid unintended side effects. For example, right now the `exit` won't happen if your `echo` fails. That doesn't happen if you make it `curl | grep && { echo ...; exit; }` -- or, perhaps easier to read, `if curl | grep; then echo ...; exit; fi`

Comment: Could also make it `xargs -0 -n 1 -P 3 sh -c '...' _` , putting the content that would otherwise be in `cme.sh` inside your `...`. No reason for `-I` when xargs' default behavior is to append to the end of the argument list.

Comment: There aren't any single quotes in the script you're calling, so it can go in an `sh -c` argument with no changes whatsoever. Just put single quotes around the whole thing; you can even keep the newlines in. It's when you embed a script that uses single quotes that things get more interesting.

Comment: (that interestingness can be avoided by switching from sh to bash and using exported functions or `declare -f` to have the shell itself be responsible for correct serialization).

Comment: `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'` is a no-no from a security perspective. You still want to use `$1` to get the value off the argv; avoids injection attacks. (The purpose of the `_` in the example I gave earlier is to fill in `$0` so the next argument goes on `$1`).

Comment: I just added a "answer" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73731777/14122 that's really intended to be more a comment on / set of suggested changes for this answer instead. Let me know when you've reviewed it and I'll delete it after that time.

Comment: btw, if you want to see the security issues I talked about yourself, try this: `printf '%s\n' '$(touch /tmp/doesnt-work)' "'"'$(touch /tmp/does-work)'"'" | xargs -d $'\n' -I{} sh -c "echo '{}'"`; hence, `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'` would be a Bad Idea if your URLs came from an untrusted source. Obviously, a real-world attack can do a lot more harm than just creating a `/tmp/does-work` file; I often try to scare people by reminding them that `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.txt` is a perfectly valid filename.

Comment: The answer I added shows that: The correct approach is _not_ to use `{}`. Single quotes aren't sufficient to make `{}` safe, as my comment above demonstrates; the only Right Thing is to entirely avoid substituting data into a string parsed as code.

Comment: Sure, you can run `xargs -I'{}' sh -c '..."$1"...' _ '{}'`, putting the sigil in an argument position instead of a code position, but what's the point? It's just making xargs do more work (searching for the `{}` string in its arguments) for no good reason.

Comment: Anyhow -- do you intend to incorporate any of those suggestions? (If not, I'll take out the "should be considered a comment" notes and let the alternative answer stand).